# Multiple backgrounds in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have the following `css`:

```
background: url(../images/clouds_bg.png) center, repeat-y -webkit-linear-gradient(#73B9FF, #FFF);
background: url(../images/clouds_bg.png) center, repeat-y linear-gradient(#73B9FF, #FFF);
```

I can't get this to work with `Internet Explorer 11`, although I have not tried IE 10 and below.

Comment: Try a different internet browser, like `Google Chrome`, `Firefox`, or `Safari`

Comment: I encounter the same problem all of the time (except I don't use multiple backgrounds...). Let's get you an answer.

Comment: @Domenico No need to switch browsers when Internet Explorer is following the rules already.

Comment: @JonathanSampson OP said it doesn't work on IE, and like most all website-related code, `CSS` doesn't always work on all browsers the same way it does on others.

Comment: @Domenico It *doesn't* work because it's written *incorrectly*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of values provided in shorthand properties is generally very important. You know that `font` requires a certain order, as does `padding`, `margin`, `border-radius`, etc. `background` is no different.

Internet Explorer follows the order of properties as documented by both the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background) and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties#Background_Properties). Both of these documentation sources list the shorthand property order as:

```
[ <color> || <image> || <repeat> || <attachment> || <position> ]
```

This means that if `repeat` is present, it must follow `color` and/or `image` if either values exist. In your case, `image` exists (as *linear-gradient*), but is out of place. Microsoft's [own documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) provides the same order.

The lesson learned here is not that Internet Explorer is wonky, but that we should always follow the examples provided by the standards bodies, and browser vendors.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kgAGf/2/

Note: MSDN does say you can provide the values "in any order," but I would encourage you to follow the specification unless otherwise stated. In this instance, Internet Explorer will work with `repeat` preceding `image` as long as `image` is a `url()` value. Using a `linear-gradient` requires the above order.

Comment: So would I need to put the linear gradient in the color or image part, seeing as though I am also including an image?

Comment: @matt1985 Check the following: http://jsfiddle.net/kgAGf/2/. As Natu said, gradients are considered *images* in the background property, so they should go *before* the repeat portion.

Comment: Works a charm! I completely forgot about order of attributes, I guess I got lazy! BTW, linking the kitten example! :-)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that IE 10/11 requires you to declare `background-image` before the other background properties (aside from background-color).  Every other browser correctly applied the rule.

```
background: url(../images/clouds_bg.png) center, linear-gradient(#73B9FF, #FFF) repeat-y;
```